# Stop increment of apex variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist, apex-variable

In my VF page I have:

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!interview.Skill_review__r}" var="skillreview"> 
                    <apex:column headerValue="Rating">
                        <apex:outputField value="{!skillreview.RatingCopy__c}" rendered="{!NOT(interviewerMode)}"/>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!i}"/>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!SkillReviewList1[i].rating}" multiselect="false" size="1" rendered="{!interviewerMode}" >
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="5" itemLabel="5"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                        <apex:variable var="i" value="{!i+1}"/>
                    </apex:column>
</apex:pageblockTable>
```

By doing this I get an error when try to get the values . Error - Subscript value 5 not valid. Must be between 0 and 4.

I see it is because in the column rating I only have 5 rows. The  `<apex:selectList value="{!SkillReviewList1[i].rating}"` should only have i value from 0 to 4. How can I control this behavior? i should only increment till 4 , I dont understand why it goes to 5 in   `<apex:selectList value="{!SkillReviewList1[i].rating}"`

Comment: You didn't happen to start off with `<apex:variable name="i" value="{!1}" />` did you?

Comment: No , I started off by <apex:variable name="i" value="{!0}" />

Comment: SkillReviewList1.size() should be the same as interview.Skill_review__r.size(). if this is not true, you'll get an exception.

Comment: this admonition in the [SFDC VF doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_variable.htm?search_text=apex:variable) is worth noting `Note: <apex:variable> does not support reassignment inside of an iteration component, such as <apex:dataTable> or <apex:repeat>. The result of doing so, e.g., incrementing the <apex:variable> as a counter, is unsupported and undefined.`  I've seen lots of folks ignore this though in countless posts

Comment: I had to use <apex:variable name="i" value="{!-1}" /> to make this work! Strange!